# how to get substring upto a first newline character from a string in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a string with large content. I have to separate out content of string before the first newline character and after the newline character.
string content is as follows:

```
std::string = "exption is theo  from my fimnct!
               mt nsamre id kjsdf dskfk djfhj
               /vonsfs/sdvfs/sdvjisd/dd.so
               dfjg dfk dflkkm sdfk "
```

from above i have to get the content of first line upto the newline charcter in another string and keep the other content remain unchanged. The characters in first line are not fixed. it is variable sting.

Comment: There is no newline character in your above string. It would be this: `\n`. Just saying.

Comment: actually, this will not compile

Comment: I agree. The preconditions of your question are simply incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try std::algorithms:

```
int main (void)
{
    std::string input(
        "exption is theo  from my fimnct!\n"
        "mt nsamre id kjsdf dskfk djfhj\n"
        "/vonsfs/sdvfs/sdvjisd/dd.so\n"
        "dfjg dfk dflkkm sdfk"
    );

    std::string first_line(input.begin(), std::find(input.begin(), input.end(), '\n'));
    std::string rest_lines(std::find(input.begin(), input.end(), '\n'), input.end());

    std::cout << first_line << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    std::cout << rest_lines << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints out

```
exption is theo  from my fimnct!
---

mt nsamre id kjsdf dskfk djfhj
/vonsfs/sdvfs/sdvjisd/dd.so
dfjg dfk dflkkm sdf
```

Comment: `std::string` has it's own `find` and find_*` functions, no need to use STL algorithms here.

Comment: `std::string::find` returns `size_t` while `std::find` returns iterator

Answer (score 5):

What about `string::substr` and `string::find`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "foo\nbar";
    std::cout << "first line: " << s.substr(0, s.find('\n')) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would do this like this:

```
std::string first, second, all = "...";
size_t pos = all.find('\n')
if(pos != std::string::npos)
{
    first = all.substr(0, pos);
    second = all.substr(pos+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`std::string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) and [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/)

Comment: without motivating example I find it hard to justify `find_first_of` over `find`

Comment: I don't see any differences between `find` and `find_first_of` for this case (we're talking about a single char). That was just the first, that came to my mind.